# How to match several numbers only?

Tags: perl

Currently, I have one issue to match several numbers only.

for example:

```
my $input1 = "1234 abc test";     - > expect - match and return 1234
my $input2 = " 1234 abc test";    - > expect - match and return 1234
my $input3 = "abc test 1234";     - > expect - match and return 1234
my $input4 = "a1234 test";         not match
my $input5 = "1234- abc test";     not match
my $input6 = "abc 12345 test";     not match
```

For the above 6 examples, only input1, input2, and input3 need to return `1234`. Others will return `not matched`.  How to code the regular expression like that?

I try to do this, but it will not work for input1 and input3.

```
if $input =~ /\s+(\d{4,4})\s+/{

}
```

Comment: In order to help you you need to describe matching rule in words. E.g. "match for words which contain only numbers and are either at the beginning or the end of a string; the number of digits can vary from 1 to 10 (for example)".  The example I am giving here is what I would deduce from your samples, but cannot be sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
/(?:^|\s)(\d{4})(?:\z|\s)/a
```

or

```
/(?<!\S)(\d{4})(?!\S)/a   # Not proceeded by a non-space and not followed by a non-space.
```

(`\d` normally matches 630 different Code Points. The `/a` causes it to only match `[0-9]` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternative: whitespace or beginning/end of string.

```
$input =~ /(?:^|\s)(\d{4})(?:$|\s)/
```

Also note that `\d` matches digits in other writing systems like "೬". Use `[0-9]` or the `/a` modifier to only match ascii digits.

Comment: [Know your character classes under different semantics](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-character-classes/) :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of ugly regex if it can be split to simplify the code....   This Perl will work it does a single pass to grab any values  and double checks for format in the second pass...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$input[1] = "1234 abc test";   #  - > expect - match and return 1234
$input[2] = " 1234 abc test";  #  - > expect - match and return 1234
$input[3] = "abc test 1234";   #  - > expect - match and return 1234
$input[4] = "a1234 test";      #   not match
$input[5] = "1234- abc test";  #   not match
$input[6] = "abc 12345 test";  #   not match

for $input (@input) {
#   $input = $input[$i];
    next if $input !~ /(.?\d{4}.?)/;
    $val = $1;
    next if $val !~ /^\s?(\d{4})\s?$/;
    $val = $1;

    printf "%s\n", $val;
}
```

Comment: This code basically grabs the 4 digits and a char before and after if they exist.  It then verifies that those extra chars is they exist are \s otherwise it fails to match.

Don't get into the habit of trying to write monolithic regex expressions if you can avoid it.  One, they are slower and two they are hard to read/understand at times.

Comment: You replaced two simple checks with about 20 operations. How is that less complex? Feel free to add spaces (`/ (?<!\S) (\d{4}) (?!\S) /xa`). As for your claims that your code is faster? I *seriously* doubt that. (Not that is matters.) All those extra operations, and starting the regex engine twice are gonna cost a lot! Anyway, you really should remove the wrong part

Comment: If you really have a problem with `next if $input !~ / (?:^|\s) (\d{4}) (?:\s|\z) /xa;`, you could use `next if !( $input =~ /\s(\d{4})\s/a || $input =~ /^(\d{4})\z/a );` ButI don't see that as a good thing at all.

Comment: Depends on the data set.  My assumption is that this will parse a stream of strings looking for lines that match the criteria.

My way will cheaply ignore any line that does not contain 4 digits sequentially.  Depending on the data this could mean large chunks of text being ignored.

The second pass is also cheap as it only looks at the extract test value.

You should see the efficiencies with very large datasets

Comment: No. When there are no matches, your code should be pretty much identical in speed to at least some of the he earlier solutions. (`.?` isn't going to be faster than `(?:^|\s)`) When there are matches, your code does a ton of extra work. So it will never be faster. Still, we're talking about such small speed amounts.